# How to make a method accessible from any other classes from the project

Tags: c#, methods

I have this very basic method that I would like to call often and in many classes.

```
public void MessageErreur(String message)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    Console.ResetColor();
}
```

I wanted to know if there was a way to just write it somewhere only once instead of creating a new one for each of my project's classes.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a static helper class:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static void MessageErreur(String message)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}
```

Then use it like

```
    Helper.MessageErreur("text");
```

P.S. If you are using the newest version of C# and .Net you can try to implement the [default interface methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods). So the code should look like:

```
interface IErrorMessager
{
    public void MessageErreur(string message)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}
```

However, the static helper implementation looks much more natural.

Answer (score 0):

for the static reusable code

```cs
public static class SharedMethods
{
    public static void SharedReusableMethod1()
    {
     
    }

}

// USAGE

private void SomeMethod()
{
    SharedMethods.SharedReusableMethod1();

}
```

For the instance methods same thing , only you need to create instance

```cs
public class InstanceMethods
{
    public void SharedReusableMethod2()
    {
     
    }

}
// USAGE
private void SomeMethod()
{
    var c = new InstanceMethods();
    c.SharedReusableMethod2();

}
```

in both cases code is reusable